# Recursive function gets stuck in a temporary loop

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with names as keys, and a list of the people they've met as values.
e.g.:

```
meetings = {'a': ['b', 'e'], 'b': ['a', 'c', 'e'], 'c': ['b', 'd'], 'd': ['c'], 'e': ['a', 'b']}
```

Now I'm trying to make a function to check if there's a 'link' between two people (with a maximum distance between these two people if specified). The variable 'distance' is the amount of people inbetween person_X and person_Y. I currently have this:

```
def had_contact_with(meetings, person_X, person_Y, distance=-1):
    if person_Y in meetings[person_X] or person_X == person_Y:
        return True
    elif distance == 0:
        return False
    elif distance == -1: #if there is no limit on the distance specified, max distance is len(meetings)
        distance = len(meetings)
    for person in meetings[person_X]:
        if had_contact_with(meetings, person, person_Y, distance-1):
            return True
```

My code works, but sometimes it gets stuck in a loop for a while. For example if I try:

```
print(had_contact_with(meetings,'a','d'))
```

It starts checking the contacts of person a, which are b and e. Then it checks person b's contacts, but person a is first in the list of b's contacts, so it just keeps checking between person a and person b, until distance becomes 0. Is there a way to stop it from going in a loop?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by maintaining a set of the nodes that you have already visited on the current path. To facilitate the use of this set, I personally prefer to create a nested function that will take care of the recursion, and keep define that set at the main function's scope, accessible to the inner function.

Also, I think your base case needs a little adjustment, as the distance of equality is one less (0) than the (remaining) distance when you have a positive `in` result (1).

```
def had_contact_with(meetings, person_X, person_Y, distance=-1):
    visited = set()
    if distance == -1:
        distance = len(meetings)
    if person_X == person_Y:
        return True
    if distance == 0:
        return False

    def recur(person_X, distance):
        if person_Y in meetings[person_X]:
            return True
        if distance == 1 or person_X in visited:
            return False
        visited.add(person_X)
        for person in meetings[person_X]:
            if recur(person, distance - 1):
                return True
        visited.remove(person_X)
        return False

    return recur(person_X, distance)
```

Comment: Hi, I probably shouldve explained the "distance" a bit better. It's the maximum amount of people between person X and Y. If there's 2 people between X and Y, the function can only return True if the specified distance is greater than 1. Distance 0 means person X and Y can only be in direct contact. I changed "distance == 1" to "distance == 0" and now it works fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good to hear it was useful to you!

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the currently checked person (person_x) from the meetings send in the sub loop. (with copy if you want to keep the initial one)